# VueJS and leaflet - need advices

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using VueJS and leaflet. i am trying to use vue-choropleth to do this:

[image]

My first question would be: it it possible to add it to the "normal map"? All i would like is that if I click on a country, this one gets red and a popup gets displayed. in the examples we get only paraguay and I wonder how to get a map with all countries https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-choropleth

Second question:

I used vue2-leaflet on another page but struggled a bit, and for this new page I am wondering if I should use leaflet directly with https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ in javascript or if I could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-choropleth

Thanks a lot! Here is what I tried but for now I don't even manage to display the map

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="mapElement" ref="mapElement"></div>
    <div id="sidecol"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { CRS, DomEvent, map, latLngBounds, latLng } from 'leaflet';
import world from './data/countries.json';
import L from 'leaflet';
export default {
  name: "repnat",
  data(){
    return {
      world:world
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    var map = L.map(this.$refs['mapElement']).setView([30, 0], 2);


    var myStyle = {
      fillColor: "grey",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };

    $('#sidecol').empty();
    var myGeojSonLayerGroup = L.geoJson(this.world, {
      onEachFeature: this.myOnEachFeature,
      style: myStyle
    }).addTo(map);

    $(".cntrys").click(function() {
      var item = $(this);
      console.log("clicked on item " + item.data("countryName"));
      myGeojSonLayerGroup.resetStyle(myGeojSonLayerGroup);
      item.data("countryLayer").setStyle({
        fillColor: "red",
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
      });
    });

  },
  methods:{
    myOnEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      var props = feature.properties;
      var item = $('<div class="cntrys"><p class="title">' + props.name + '</a></p></div>');
      item.data("countryLayer", layer);
      item.data("countryName", props.name);
      $('#sidecol').append(item);
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
@import "../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

#map {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
```

This works well though

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <l-map :center="[-23.752961, -57.854357]" :zoom="6" style="height: 500px;" :options="mapOptions">
      <l-choropleth-layer :data="pyDepartmentsData" titleKey="department_name" idKey="department_id" :value="value" :extraValues="extraValues" geojsonIdKey="dpto" :geojson="worldGeojson" :colorScale="colorScale">
        <template slot-scope="props">
          <l-info-control :item="props.currentItem" :unit="props.unit" title="Department" placeholder="Hover over a department"/>
          <l-reference-chart title="Girls school enrolment" :colorScale="colorScale" :min="props.min" :max="props.max" position="topright"/>
        </template>
      </l-choropleth-layer>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { InfoControl, ReferenceChart, ChoroplethLayer } from 'vue-choropleth'
import { geojson } from './data/py-departments-geojson'
import worldGeojson from './data/world.json'
import { pyDepartmentsData } from './data/py-departments-data'
import {LMap} from 'vue2-leaflet';
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: { 
    LMap,
    'l-info-control': InfoControl, 
    'l-reference-chart': ReferenceChart, 
    'l-choropleth-layer': ChoroplethLayer 
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pyDepartmentsData,
      worldGeojson,
      colorScale: ["e7d090", "e9ae7b", "de7062"],
      value: {
        key: "amount_w",
        metric: "% girls"
      },
      extraValues: [{
        key: "amount_m",
        metric: "% boys"
      }],
      mapOptions: {
        attributionControl: false
      },
      currentStrokeColor: '3d3213'
    }
  },
}
</script>
<style>
/* @import "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"; */
body {
  background-color: #e7d090;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
#map {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
```